# command line argument in C

Tags: c, command-line-arguments

I was doing my programs Python, so not much familiar with C.
I am doing a program on creating a binary tree in C. I am using an "insert" function created by me . The goal is that for typing "insert " in command line, the function should work. But I have not much idea regarding how to get and parse command line arguments in C. Can anyone help?

Comment: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson14.html

Comment: there are quite a few examples doing a quick [google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=command+line+c+simple+example&oq=command+line+c+simple+example)

Answer (score 0):

http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson14.html

```
int main( int argc, char *argv[])
```

This should be the declaration of your main function. `argc` is the amount of arguments. `argv[]` is an array that contains each command-line argument as a string, the program name is `argv[0]` so the first argument will be `argv[1]`. I'm not a C programmer, so this might not be good info, I highly recommend checking out the link.

Answer (score 0):

Use a library to handle the low-level details, such as [`getopt`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Getopt).  The code is much more involved than with Python's [argparse](http://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#module-argparse) or [getopt](http://docs.python.org/3/library/getopt.html#module-getopt), but is similar in concept.  (the wikipedia article to which I linked contains example C code using getopt)

Answer (score 0):

Command line arguments are passed during run time.

You have to specify the number  of arguments and also a char pointer to point to these arguments. This is done in main() syntax itself.
Void main(int argc, char* argv)

In order to compile and generate an executable  in CC compiler,
cc -o exec_name program_name.c

In order to run,
exec_name arg1 arg2.........

It is to be noted that the exec_name is also considered as an argument